# Regular expression to validate minimum value of formatted currency in asp.net data annotation

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, data-annotations

```
^(?:[3-9]\d|[1-9]\d\d|[1-9],\d{3})(?:,\d{3})+
```

Above regular expression validates a formatted currency with minimum value of 30,000
Check here https://regex101.com/r/35l44o/1

Now I want to change it to make minimum value of 1,000,000

Can anyone help?

Comment: Asp or JavaScript?

Comment: javascript. using it in asp.net mvc data-annotations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work

https://regex101.com/r/iDkBPl/1

```
^(?:[1-9]{1,})(?:,\d{3})(?:,\d{3})+
```

Comment: Reduce it more `^[1-9]+(?:,\d{3}){2,}`

Comment: @anubhava Nice one.

Comment: ++ It is anyway your nice solution, I just reduced it a bit